# Sort "Assigned To" field containing multiple values

Tags: list, column, custom-list

Have assigned default column "Assigned To" for new list "Issue Tracking" with following settings:

1. Require that this column contains information: **No**
2. Allow multiple selections: **Yes**
3. Allow selection of: **People and Groups**
4. Choose from: **SharePoint Group**

SharePoint prevents me from sorting this column in View "All Issues", with message, "This column type cannot be sorted."

Is it possible to sort columns containing multiple values, and if so, how?

Running SharePoint 2007 SP1 (KB936984, KB942390) December 11, 2007, 12.0.0.6219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick google search it looks like you may need to change multiple selections to NO and or only search for People not groups.

See link below for more details:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/b748bb03-4881-4aa5-9c87-bd4558b9201c

Answer (score 1):

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38020258/708685, you should be able to. While your column Assigned To has allow multiple values enabled, fill in all of your data as needed. Once done, turn off allow multiple values. SharePoint will pop up a warning about how this data may be lost (so far has never happened to me). Hit okay, then modify the view you want sorted, "Assigned to" should now show up on the drop down of columns to sort by.

Should keep in mind though that if you are sorting by multiple terms and you put them in inconsistently, you could have, in my example, "Conway"; "Myrtle Beach" being with the rest of the "Conway"s and "Myrtle Beach"; "Conway" with the rest of the "Myrtle Beach"s when you probably wanted them to be together.